# Specific item in list not in the same format as others

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, list

My problem is this: I'm populating an unordered list with links, everything formats correctly except of the indexLink- it's dedented a bit. I can't find the problem, I've double checked each part, rewritten the code containing the link from scratch, and I still can't find the issue. Here's my javascript:

```
function addCrumb() {
  /* reads from localStorage and determines which links go where */
  for (i = hIndexCount; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (localStorage.history.charAt(i) === "a") {
      ridingHood[i] = '<a href="aboutme.html"><span class="aboutMeLink">About Me</span></a>';
    } else if (localStorage.history.charAt(i) === "e") {
      ridingHood[i] = '<a href="experiments.html"><span class="experimentsLink">Experiments</span></a>';
    } else if (localStorage.history.charAt(i) === "i") {
      ridingHood[i] = '<a href="../index.html"><span class="indexLink">Sprit Index</span></a>';
    } else if (localStorage.history.charAt(i) === "p") {
      ridingHood[i] = '<a href="professional.html"><span class="professionalLink">Professional</span></a>';
    } else if (localStorage.history.charAt(i) === "s") {
      ridingHood[i] = '<a href="school.html"><span class="schoolLink">School</span></a>';
    }
  }

  //window.alert(ridingHood + " " + h + " " + localStorage.history.length);

  displayCrumbs();
}

function displayCrumbs() {
  ridingHood[hIndexCount] = '<li><span class="firstLink">' + ridingHood[hIndexCount] + '</span></li>';
  ridingHood[hIndexCount - 1] = '<li><span class="secondLink">' + ridingHood[hIndexCount - 1] + '</span></li>';
  ridingHood[hIndexCount - 2] = '<li><span class="thirdLink">' + ridingHood[hIndexCount - 2] + '</span></li>';
  ridingHood[hIndexCount - 3] = '<li><span class="fourthLink">' + ridingHood[hIndexCount - 3] + '</span></li>';

  /* cycles through and displays each ridingHood index */
  for (i = hIndexCount; i >= 0; i--) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("history")[0].innerHTML += ridingHood[i];
  }
}
```

the html:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="history">

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks for your time! Let me know if you need anything else. :)

edit: figured I could just upload the website to the student server for a live example, [here we go](http://cois-linux.austincc.edu/~u2043906/finalproject/index.html)!

Comment: Maybe you have CSS that's changing the style of `.indexLink`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `index.css` you have:

```
.aboutMeLink, .schoolLink, .experimentsLink, .professionalLink {
  height: 4.2em;
  width: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border-left: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-right: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  -webkit-transition: background .6s ease-in-out, width .4s ease-in-out, border-color .2s ease-in-out .5s;
  -moz-transition: background .6s ease-in-out, width .4s ease-in-out, border-color .2s ease-in-out .5s;
  -ms-transition: background .6s ease-in-out, width .4s ease-in-out, border-color .2s ease-in-out .5s;
  -o-transition: background .6s ease-in-out, width .4s ease-in-out, border-color .2s ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: background .6s ease-in-out, width .4s ease-in-out, border-color .2s ease-in-out .5s;
}
```

You don't have `.indexLink` included in this style, so that link gets different styling from the other links. Add `.indexLink` to it.

Or, instead of listing all these classes, give those elements a common class like `sidebarLink`, and apply the style to that class.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it, I can't believe I missed that lol. They all have separate colors, so that's why they need unique classes.